# Making a void function that returns a value

Tags: c++

I was asked to make a void function that returns a value. For example if we have something like:

```
int add(int n, int k){
   return n+k; 
}
```

Now since *void* doesn't return anything, how can the function possible return a value? Is there some hidden way to do that for:

```
void add(int n, int k){
   //returning the sum of n and k in a void function
}
```

Or this is impossible like I first thought of?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as expressed.  What was the context? Was this a real world problem or a puzzle/interview question?  If the latter, then callback could be used but it doesn't _return_ the value.  Since this is C++ (therefore an OO langyage) it could also pass the result forward, following the Tell Don''t Ask idiom. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Comment: Yes, it was the latter! Thank you for that, I will look it over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an output parameter, eg:

```
void add(int n, int k, int &result) {
   result = n+k;
}

...

int sum;
add(1, 2, sum);
// use sum as needed...
```

Or:

```
void add(int n, int k, int *result) {
   *result = n+k;
}

...

int sum;
add(1, 2, &sum);
// use sum as needed...
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking something stupid, but how it returns here the *result*? Doesn't it only stores the sum in that reference variable, but still doesn't return anything?

Comment: @Reformed that is correct.  The sum is stored in a separate variable provided by the caller.  There is no way a `void` function can **return** anything other than a `void` (ie, `return void();` is a valid statement, as is `return func();` where `func()` also returns a `void`).

Comment: I see, and now we can make use of that variable making something like a pseudo-return.

Comment: @Reformed This is more commonly called a reference.

Answer (score 2):

It is, by definition, not possible for a `void` function to return a value. That's what `void` means in that context.

There are a number of ways that a `void` function can convey information to its caller:

- It can take a pointer argument
- It can take a reference argument
- It can assign a value to a global variable (or any object visible to the caller)

If you want a function to return a value, don't define it as `void`.

Comment: @Reformed defining a return type as `void` is fine in general, just not when you actually want to `return` a value.  Use `void` whenever you DON'T want to `return` a value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, of course. May I also ask how should've the function be written in the pointers case ? 

    I tried this:
   void add(int n, int k, int *result) {
    result = n+k;
  }
   ...
   int sum;
   add(1, 2, &sum); 

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Reformed You need to dereference the pointer in order to assign a value to the variable that it is pointing at: `void add(int n, int k, int *result) { *result = n+k; }`